# When to create multiple executor service per application java

Tags: java

When is it a good idea to create more than one executor service per run of a program/application? Why would you do it, instead of just starting up `executors.newcachedthreadpool()` at the beginning and submitting all callables to it.

Answer (score 8):

- You might need different flavours (say a fixed thread pool or a scheduled executor)
- Encapsulation: if a specific class needs to run things through an executor, it makes sense that this class be responsible to decide its execution policy, which is an implementation detail
- Specialisation - corollary of the previous point:

  - some tasks need many threads (typically network tasks)
  - while others only need a few (CPU-bound task)
  - and some should only use one (if you read/write on your local hard drive for example)
- There certainly are situations where you want to pass an executor to an object because you want the calling code to control how some tasks will be executed

Bottom line, I can't think of a reason why, for a sufficiently large project, you would want to just use one thread pool for your whole program.

Answer (score 1):

A typical use case for adding an executor service, is when you want your service to use a different thread pooling strategy, or have two different pool sizes. Your application may contain a class of runnables that you would like to submit to a large, fixed size pool, and another kind of runnables where you would want a smaller pool.

Keep in mind that ExecutorService has several implementations:

1. [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)
2. [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html)

Have a look at the constructor parameters for ThreadPoolExecutor, these are all things you may want to tune, based on the kind of tasks you are submitting:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, 
   int maximumPoolSize, 
   long keepAliveTime, 
   TimeUnit unit, 
   BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue)
```

Notice that you can also pass in a Queue, so you can control the queuing strategy that your thread pool uses.